# IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection from jsp tomcat in linux

Tags: oracle, jsp, tomcat, centos7

I have centos server and i have installed oracle and tomcat (both in same server) and it's working fine.
I have access oracle also from my local system using sql developer.
I have created a simple program in both java and jsp with oracle connectivity

java code:

```
import java.sql.*;  
class OracleCon{  
   public static void main(String args[]){  
      try{  
       //step1 load the driver class  
       Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  

       //step2 create  the connection object  
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
        "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","oracle");  

        //step3 create the statement object  
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  

        //step4 execute query  
         ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp");  
         while(rs.next())  
             System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3));  

            //step5 close the connection object  
            con.close();  

           } catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}  
       }  
}
```

this is working fine,but when i am using same code in jsp on tomcat server in centos OS
this is giving following

> IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

there a problem java code working fine and giving output but same code in jsp giving error.

I have search found lot of solution and try but that is not work and what the reason that working for java program but giving error in jsp tomcat.